# Can CFC and ladder programs run in single codesys project

Tags: logic, coding-style, cfc, codesys, ladder-logic

Can someone please tell me how to run ladder program (PRG) and cfc(PRG)program in one codesys project.

Moreover,what function should I use in codesys CFC programming to take multiple inputs in WORD data type and output will be the one which will have some value?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many programs as you want of any kind:

[image: Creating new Program]

Just make sure to add them into the Task Configuration for them to run:

[image]